# Как передать переменную из вида в контроллер

Tags: php, mvc

Недавно начал разбираться с mvc, переделываю старый сайт под mvc.
Возник вопрос как можно передать переменную из вида обратно в контроллер
В виде выводятся комментарии в цикле:

```
foreach( $data[dataRows] as $row) {     
    $Id=$row->id;  
    $DateTime=$row->datetime;  
    $Title=$row->title;
```

нужно переменную $Id обратно передавать в контролер
чтобы ее можно была использовать в модели
при выборки из базы :

```
class Dashboards extends Controller {  
public function __construct(){  
      $this->dashboardModel = $this->model('Dashboard');  
    }

public function index($Id){  
$RowsApproved  = $this->dashboardModel->getApproved_($Id);
```

Comment: скорее всего правильно было бы передавать переменные из контроллера в представление, а не наоборот.

Comment: Передавать что-то из вьюхи в контроллер, как и получать напрямую данные вьюхой из модели - это хоть и допускается, но не приветствуется.   У вас же $data гонится из модели, вот там подготовьте данные и передайте их в контроллер. Может сделать отдельный метод для этого.

Comment: Если допускается то, как все же передать $Id обратно в контроллер.